# Access Blob Storage (image with sas with Allowed IP addresses)

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-blob-storage

I'm unable to access blob url from virtual machine .
I have both a storage account and a vm in same region ,
I created a blob (piture ) and shared accees via saas token with Allowed IP addresses , while it works when i test on my machine and other machines , but in the vm it's not working and unable to see the blob it's like even i give access to the vm public IP  , it dosent work

[image]

Comment: Overly restrictive NSG rule?

Comment: I have no idea ,i'm testing on test envirnment and here is the inbound rules ,

https://strtodelete.blob.core.windows.net/blb/inbound.png?sp=r&st=2022-08-03T09:45:04Z&se=2024-08-03T17:45:04Z&sv=2021-06-08&sr=b&sig=RNeFQDQLP6g8PHvUDS2iaAZzvtSzkvX7O50%2BlTCjvSc%3D

Comment: It would be the outbound rules if anything

Comment: Well , there are only the default rules here ..

Answer (score 1):

These issues may occur if you are using same region in storage and VM.  If the storage account and the VM are in the same area ***Traffic passes across the Azure backbone network***. If you want use in the same region, you can use ***Virtual network rules to allow same-region requests. and utilize private Azure IP addresses for communication***

Try to utilize [service endpoints,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#grant-access-from-a-virtual-network) by constantly keeping traffic going to Azure Storage on the Azure backbone network, ***service endpoints offer the best routing.*** This optimal route overrides any routes directing traffic through on-premises or virtual appliances.

***Go to your virtual networks -> service end point -> add -> select Microsoft. Storage -> your public Ip subnet***

[image]

Try to enable Firewall rules that permit access from particular virtual networks and from public IP address ranges can coexist on the same storage account.

***In your storage account -> networking -> firewall & virtual networks -> use your public Ip*** as below

[image]

Try to Allow outbound traffic from VM to blob storage using port 443 or 449

[image]

***Reference:*** [Azure Service Endpoint Overview and Configuration](https://medium.com/rupesh-tiwari/azure-service-endpoint-overview-and-configuration-ac0f6383c05b) *by Rupesh*

---

Alternatively, you can use [azure private endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-storage-portal). Thus, you cannot restrict from access the way of traffic intended to storage account always remains in private IP space it can access from it.